# Isomorphisms between subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $U$ and $W$ two subspaces of a vector space $V$.  Let $T: U \times W \to V$ be a function, defined by $T(u, w) = u + w$.

Show that

> **i)** $T$ is a linear transformation,
>
> **ii)** Image of $T$ is the subspace $U+W$,
>
> **iii)** $\ker T = \{(u,-u) \mid u \in U \cap W\}$ is isomorphic to $U \cap W$.

Well, **i)** is rather easy.

Any thoughts about **ii)** and **iii)**?

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much, Sammy!

Answer (score 1):

For (ii) note that 
$$
U+W=\{u+w:u\in U, w\in W\}
$$
But then
\begin{align*}
\DeclareMathOperator{Image}{Image}\Image(T)
&= \{T(u,w):u\in U,w\in W\} \\
&= \{u+w:u\in U,w\in W\} \\
&= U+W
\end{align*}

Comment: Hi guys, Let T:V--->V be a linear transformation. How to show that T^2=0, if and only if ImT⊂ Ker T?

Answer (score 0):

For ii), there isn't much to say: it's the definition of the sum of two subspaces. 
As for iii), just use the definition of the kernel:
$$(u,w)\in\ker T\iff w=-u$$
so $u\in W$ (hence in $U\cap W$ , as well as $w$), and a vector in $\ker T$ can be written as: $$(u,w)=(u,-u)\in (U\cap W)\times(U\cap W)$$
Conversely, it is trivial that such a vector is in $\ker T$.

Comment: Bernard and Brian, thank you very much for your help!